# Reading a list of names with fgets() results in string + "\r" Question

Tags: c

Perhaps this has a simple answer. I am reading a list of names from a supplied text file and after using gdb I have realized that what is actually being read is "\r" (e.g. "Rob\r"). Each name in the file is on a single line. When I create my own text file however and read in a name there does not appear to be a \r included in the string. Why is the \r being included from this particular text file that I was given?

It appears it is behaving as a newline char, but when I do something like printf("Hello,\rWorld);
only World is printed as output. I have read what the \r is, but I am not entirely sure how the text file is supplying this information to my C program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000

typedef struct _Alloc {
    char * wpt;
    int wsize;
} Alloc;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    //char* filename = (char *)"test.txt";

    //open a text file; 
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        return 1;
    }
    
    char * token;
    
    int arraySize = 100;
    Alloc** alloc = malloc(sizeof(Alloc*) * arraySize);
    
    if (!alloc) {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL){
        token = strtok(str, "\n");
        size_t wsize= strlen(token)+1;
 
        void *request;
        request = sbrk(wsize);
        strcpy((char *)request,token);
        
        alloc[i] = (Alloc *)malloc(sizeof(Alloc));
        alloc[i]->wpt = request;
        alloc[i]->wsize  = wsize;
        
        i++;
        
        if(i==arraySize){
            break;
        }
    }
    
    fclose(fp); 
    
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<arraySize; j++){
        printf("starting address=%p, size=%d, p=%s\n",alloc[j]->wpt,alloc[j]->wsize, (char *)alloc[j]->wpt);
    }
    
    for (j = 0; j < arraySize; ++j) {
        free(alloc[j]);
    }
    free(alloc);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buff[ strcspn( buff, "\r\n") ] = 0;`

Comment: Your program?  You need to supply us with source or else how can we help.

Answer (score 2):

Some operating systems, most notably Windows, uses `\r\n` as newline sequence. Whenever you write `\n` to a text-file (opened in text-mode) then the system translates it to `\r\n`.

Conversely, when reading from a text file (opened in text-mode) the system will translate `\r\n` into plain `\n`.

That you get a carriage-return `\r` in your array is an indication of one of two possible things:

1. You have transferred the file from Windows to a non-Windows system, which probably uses plain `\n` as the single newline. On such systems there won't be any translations, and the carriage-return will be read as any other non-newline character.

   Examples of such systems include Linux and macOS.
2. You opened the file in *binary* mode, where no such newline translation is made.

Judging by the code, especially the header files (which are specific for systems like Linux and macOS), alternative 1 is the problem. Some systems come with a `dos2unix` command, which reads a file and translates all `\r\n` sequences into `\n`. If your system doesn't have that command installed, you could look for such a package which installs it, or write such a utility yourself (it's very simple).

Comment: I am only seeing a \r not \r\n. Is it possible that it is from a Windows text file which has simply the \r and my Linux OS is translating that to \n. This would make sense as when I print the list of names they are printed out each on a separate line.

Comment: @Thunderbird Have you looked at the file using a hex editor? What are the actual line-endings in the file (as shown by the hex-editor)? If it's really only `\r` then those are more likely old MacOS files (from way before macOS, and before MacOS X), as that was the only known system using `\r` as line-endings.

Comment: I will look into the hex editor. I've never used one, but that would be great if it would tell me the actual line-ending. Thanks.

Comment: @Thunderbird On Windows it's `\r\n` which is `0x0d 0x0a`. On Linux and macOS (since MaxOS X) it's `\n` which is `0x0a`, and on older MaxOS (version 9 and earlier) it's `\r` which is `0x0d`.

Answer (score 0):

After using the hex editor in vim each name is followed by a 0d0a which makes sense now. The code reads in a name up to but not including the newline but also takes in the 0d which is the \r.